# Problem with Justifying the Formula for First Order Seperable Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, intuition

I am reading this text http://www.math-cs.gordon.edu/courses/ma225/handouts/sepvar.pdf to justify the method to solve first order seperable differentiable equations, where we are told first told that: [image]

and then: [image]

Now, while I can understand 1), I am struggling to understand how exactly the integral on the left hand side of 3) surmounts to $$\int n(y) dy$$ since $\frac{dy}{dx}$ can't be treated as a fraction.

Comment: @mvw Can you please clarify?

Comment: I believe it's just a matter of substitution. You have $\int_0^x n\big(y(\tilde x)\big) y'(\tilde x) \mathrm d \tilde x  $ and substitute $ t := y(\tilde x), \mathrm d t = y(\tilde x)'\mathrm d \tilde x$ to obtain $\int_{y(0)}^{y(x)} n(t)\mathrm d t  $

Comment: Note that it is incredibly misleading to say "integrate both sides with respect to $x$" as the text does. You are integrating with respect to some parameter, such that the limits of integration are $x_0$ (usually set to zero) and $x$. This way, integration results in an expression like $F(y(x),y(x_0))=G(x,x_0)$, which can hopefully be inverted to give $y(x)=H(x,x_0,y(x_0))$. 

For some reason, many texts present it in such a way, especially those aimed at applications or physics. But the objective is to have $x$ as the limit of integration, so that you can invert for the solution!

Comment: @krvolok Thanks a lot, I was just actually wondering if it intuitively makes sense to integrate both sides with respect to both sides.

Comment: @krvolok I was wondering how we can justify in this case that dt equals dy, or can be treated as dy? Do we treat y as t?

Comment: @krvolok Sorry, no need to reply, I have seen what you meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you consider $y$ as a function of $x$ then $\frac{dy}{dx}= y'(x)$

to compute your integral just consider the change of variable formula:

$$\int n(y(x))y'(x)\, dx = \int n(y) dy $$